# Rails - How can I access the variable I pass to the controller from the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I have this in my view:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <% if user.teacher == current_user.teacher || current_user.role == "admin" %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.username %></td>
    <td><%= user.email %></td>
    <td><%= user.teacher %></td>
    <td><%= user.role %></td>
    <td><%= user.admin %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Problems', student_problems_path(user) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

So, I pass `user` as a parameter to `student_problems_path`. In my `UsersController` I have:

```
def student_problems
    @problems = Problem.all
    @user = user.email
end
```

But, Rails tell me the following:

```
undefined local variable or method `user' for #<UsersController:0x3d79208
```

How do I gain access to the `user` variable I pass to the `UsersController` from the view? Thanks!

**Edit**

Here are my routes:

```
                  root        /                              problems#new
        feedback_index POST   /feedback(.:format)            feedback#create
          new_feedback GET    /feedback/new(.:format)        feedback#new
      new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
          user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
  destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
         user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
     new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
    edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                       PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#ed
     user_registration PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#up
              problems GET    /problems(.:format)            problems#index
                       POST   /problems(.:format)            problems#create
           new_problem GET    /problems/new(.:format)        problems#new
          edit_problem GET    /problems/:id/edit(.:format)   problems#edit
               problem GET    /problems/:id(.:format)        problems#show
                       PUT    /problems/:id(.:format)        problems#update
                       DELETE /problems/:id(.:format)        problems#destroy
                 users GET    /users(.:format)               users#index
                       POST   /users(.:format)               users#create
              new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)           users#new
             edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit
                  user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
                       PUT    /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
                       DELETE /users/:id(.:format)           users#destroy
            help_about GET    /help/about(.:format)          help#about
          problems_new GET    /problems/new(.:format)        problems#new
                  data        /data(.:format)                problems#data
      student_problems        /student_problems(.:format)    users#student_problems
```

Comment: student_problems_path looks like a nested resource path?  is it?  but the error shows user controller.  are you sure it is calling the correct action.  by setting an instance variable, that gives the view access to it, I would check and verify that you are calling the correct method.

Comment: can you post the code of route.rb?

Comment: I think you should modify your routes.rb file code related to student_problems because you didn't define the id of your user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following:

```
# pass the following to your helper:
student_problems_path(user_email: user.email)

# now the URL will be /student_problems?user_email=user@gmail.com
# and in the controller do:

def student_problems
  @user = params[:user_email]
  @problems = Problem.all
end
```

Comment: Ok, I was worried that would give me `current_user`. I want the student user whose problem set I will be viewing. This will work for that you mean?

Comment: It won't be the `current_user` since you're passing in an ID and then looking it up in the database.

Comment: can you check out my routes? Do they look ok? Sorry I am still learning how all this routing stuff works.

Comment: Your code makes it sound as if a `user` has-a `problem`. It does not. A `problem` just has a `:user` attribute that stores whichever user did the `problem`.

Comment: Ok, I've changed my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. `@user = params([:user_email])` returns an `ArgumentError` ... `1 for 0`

Comment: Got it...thanks! I think it should be `params[:user_email]` instead of `params([:user_email])`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the detail of your problem, but if you want to get the id of user in student_problems action then you can use the following code:

```
@user_id = params[:id]
```

if you want to any more solution then specify the problem detail with code. Thanks